# "Could not scan for classes inside" with Ext:perfectlightbox

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Working with extension manager in TYPO3 7.6 I see this message now and then:

> "Could not scan for classes inside "/typo3conf/ext/perfectlightbox/Classes/" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder"

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create the empty directory `Classes` within the extension directory. This will fix this issue and the error message will disapear.

You can also load the latest version of this extension [from GitHub](https://github.com/beniediek/perfectlightbox) where some other things are fixed. The developer didn't released a new version to TYPO3 Extension Repository so that's the best way to get along with this extension.